# Multiple ManyToMany in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

Problem relating to driving licences. A licence has a named person who is assiged multiple categories of driving skills.  Each category of driving skill has a single renewal date and possible multiple related restrictions

> `Name` `Lic Cat` `Renewal date` `Restrictions`
>   `Tommy` `AM` `12/05/15` `44.01, 101, 999`
>   `Tommy` `E+B` `14/12/16`
>   `Tommy` `C` `18/04/18` `101`
>   `TG` `E+C` `14/12/16` `90, 101, 999,`
>   `TG` `B` `18/04/18` `105`

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

class DrivingLicenceCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=11)

class IssuingBody(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

class DrivingLicence(models.Model):
    employee_id     = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    driver_number   = models.CharField(max_length=49)
    permit_number   = models.CharField(max_length=49)
    issuing_body    = models.ForeignKey(IssuingBody)
    expiry_date     = models.DateField()

class DrivingLicenceRestrictions(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=21)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)

class DrivingLicenceCategoryRestrictions(models.Model):
    licence_category    = models.ForeignKey(DrivingLicenceCategory)
    licence_restriction = models.ForeignKey(DrivingLicenceRestrictions)
    expiry_date         = models.DateField()

class DrivingLicenceDetail(models.Model):
    driving_licence         = models.ForeignKey(DrivingLicence)
    category_restriction    = models.ManyToManyField(DrivingLicenceCategoryRestrictions)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from drvlic.models import *

class DrvLicIssuingBodyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('^name', )

class DrvLicCategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('^name',)

class DrvLicRestrictionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('^name', )
    list_display        = ('id', 'name', 'description',)

class DrvLicLicenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('^employee',)

class DrvLicCategoryRestrictionsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields       = ('^employee',)
    filter_horizontal   = ('licence_category', 'licence_restriction')

admin.site.register(DrvLicIssuingBody, DrvLicIssuingBodyAdmin)
admin.site.register(DrvLicCategory, DrvLicCategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(DrvLicRestrictions, DrvLicRestrictionsAdmin)
admin.site.register(DrvLicLicence, DrvLicLicenceAdmin)
admin.site.register(DrvLicCategoryRestrictions, DrvLicCategoryRestrictionsAdmin)
```

Is my model correct to produce the table above in Django Admin or should the model be different?  How is admin.py set up to allow access and enter the data?

Django is telling me that `'DrvLicCategoryRestrictionsAdmin.filter_horizontal[0]' must be a ManyToManyField'`.  This is irrevelent if the models.py are constructed incorrectly, I think.

Comment: as per the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal and as the error suggests it should be a M2M field. Seems like you have used a Foreign Key there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the '^' for the search field. Just `search_fields = 'name'` should suffice.
To display a ManyToManyField, you need to loop through all associated objects. But, even before that point, I think you need to restructure your models to have one 'all encompassing' model that holds that table you are trying to produce. So, something like:

models.py

```
class License(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    category = models.ManyToMany(DrivingLicenceCategory)
    restriction = models.ManyToMany(DrivingLicenceRestrictions)
    expiry_date = models.DateField()

    def get_categories(self):
        return ",<br>".join([a.name for a in self.category.all()])

    def get_restrictions(self):
        return ",<br>".join([a.name for a in self.restriction.all()])
```

admin.py

```
class LicenseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('employee', 'get_categories', 'get_restrictions', 'expirary_date')
```